# Tsunetero from tsundere

Tags: translation, meaning

I once heard a word and it’s “tsunetero” which is kinda a verb for tsundere but when I googled the word I couldn’t find it anywhere and I’m questioning myself if this word really exist or I made it up. 
I know what is tsun tsun and tsundere and when I google these two words I can see results and meanings  except for “tsunetero” So is it really a word ?

P.s I heard it from anime but I can’t remember which one

Answer (score 3):

If you can't remember where you heard it any answer is going to be a guess.

Mine is that it is a version of 拗ねる (suneru), possibly 'suneteru', for 'he/she's pouting/sulking'.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to BJCUAI's guess, there's also [抓る]{tsuneru} ("to pinch"), which would conjugate to [抓てる]{tsunete ru} ("he / she / it is pinching").